# Longest Rubik's cube algorithm - maximization problem

Tags: optimization, gcd-and-lcm, rubiks-cube

For a given Rubik's cube algorithm $A$ let $\mathfrak C(A)$ be the number of times, we have to repeat algorithm $A$ to get back to where we've started. For example if $A=RUR'U'$ then $\mathfrak C(A)=6$ The question is:
What is the greatest value of $\mathfrak C(A)$, we can achieve?
This question is equivalent to following maximization problem:
**Maximize $LCM(a_1,a_2,...a_i,b_1,b_2,...b_j)$ under the following conditions:
$$~a_1,a_2,...a_i,b_1,b_2,...,b_j \in \mathbb N_+~$$
$$a_1+a_2+...+a_i=8$$
$$b_1+b_2+...+b_j=12$$
$$2 \ | \ (a_1+a_2+...+a_i+b_1+b_2+...+b_j)$$**
Where LCM is Least Common Multiple function.
Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Wikipedia's article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubik%27s_Cube_group#Group_structure) on the Rubik's cube group says that the largest order of any element in the group is 1260. For instance, $RU^2D'BD'$ is one such move.